# Como puedo volver a usar el select que use para agregar un registro y lo use en el actualizar

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una tabla user que esta relacionada 1 a muchos con otras 4 tablas, ya tengo el select que me trae los datos de las tablas foraneas(profile, udn, statustypey usertype ) y ahora quiero que a la hora de editar el registro me aparesca de nuevo ese select para poder elegir otra opcion
Este es mi controllador User

```
public function index()
{
    return view("user.index")->with("users", User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $profile = Profile::all();
    $statustype = StatusType::all();
    $udn = Udn::all();
    $usertype = UserType::all();
    return view('user.create', compact('profile', 'statustype', 'udn', 'usertype'));
}
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $user=new User;
    $profile=new Profile;
    $statustype=new StatusType;
    $udn=new Udn;
    $usertype=new UserType;
    $user->first_name=$request->first_name;
    $user->last_name=$request->last_name;
    $user->email=$request->email;
    $user->password=$request->password;
    $user->profile_id=$request->profile_id;
    $user->status_type_id=$request->status_type_id;
    $user->udn_id=$request->udn_id;
    $user->user_type_id=$request->user_type_id;
    $user->save();   
    return redirect("panel/user");
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{   
    $user=User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('user.show', compact('user'));
}
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{   
    $user=User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('user.edit', compact('user'));
}
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(CreateUserRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user=User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    return redirect("panel/user");
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user=User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->delete();
    return redirect("panel/user");
}
```

}

Esta es mi vista edit donde solo pinto en su value en un input quiero un select para modificarlo

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('user.update', $user->id)}}" id="form-search">
        {{ csrf_field() }}     
    <div>
       <label for="">Nombre: </label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{$user->first_name}}">
       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Apellidos: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{$user->last_name}}">
    </div>        
    <div>
        <label>Correo: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}">
    </div>        
    <div>
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{$user->password}}">
    </div>
     <div>
        <label>Perfil: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profile_id" value="{{$user->profile_id}}">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Tipo de estado: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="status_type_id" value="{{$user->status_type_id}}">
    </div> 
    <div>
        <label>Udn: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="udn_id" value="{{$user->udn_id}}">
    </div> 
    <div>
        <label>Tipo de usuario: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_type_id" value="{{$user->user_type_id}}">
    </div>  
        <br>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Y esta es mi vista donde uso el select para agregar el registro

```
     <form method="post" action="{{route('user.store')}}" class="" id="form-search">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div>
        <label>Nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name">
    </div>        
    <div>
        <label>Apellidos: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name">
    </div>        
    <div>
        <label>Correo electrónico: </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
    </div>        
    <div>
        <label>Contraseña: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>        
    <div>
        <label>Perfil: </label>
        <select class="form-control" name='profile_id'>
           <option value="" selected disabled>---Selecciona una opción---</option>
            @foreach($profile as $profile)
               <option value='{{ $profile->id }}'> {{ $profile->name }} </option>
           @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Tipo de estatus: </label>
        <select class="form-control" name='status_type_id'>
           <option value="" selected disabled>---Selecciona una opción---</option>
            @foreach($statustype as $statustype)
                <option value='{{ $statustype->id }}'> {{ $statustype->name }} </option>
           @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>         
    <div>
        <label>Udn: </label>
        <select class="form-control" name='udn_id'>
           <option value="" selected disabled>---Selecciona una opción---</option>
            @foreach($udn as $udn)
                <option value='{{ $udn->id }}'> {{ $udn->name }} </option>
           @endforeach
        </select>

    </div>      
    <div>
        <label>Tipo de usuario: </label>
        <select class="form-control" name='user_type_id'>
           <option value="" selected disabled>---Selecciona una opción---</option>
            @foreach($usertype as $usertype)
                <option value='{{ $usertype->id }}'> {{ $usertype->name }} </option>
           @endforeach
        </select>
    </div> 
        <br>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Alguien que me ayude gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que suelo hacer es utilizar la misma vista para "crear" y "editar". Simplemente le paso distintas variables.

[LaravelCollective](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html) ayuda mucho a la construcción de formularios porque levanta automáticamente los valores ya cargados (los nombres de los inputs tienen que ser igual al de tus relaciones o campos), te recomiendo que le pegues una mirada.

No se como se llaman los campos de tus relaciones, así que eso revisalo.
Ojo porque tu botón de "Cancelar" es un `submit`.

```
public function create()
{
    $user = new User(); // Creo un usuario vacío para simplificar la lógica de la vista
    $profiles = Profile::all();
    $statustypes = StatusType::all();
    $udns = Udn::all();
    $usertypes = UserType::all();
    $action = route('user.store'); // Action del formulario
    $method = 'POST'; // Method del formulario

    return view('user.create', compact('user', 'profiles', 'statustypes', 'udns', 'usertypes', 'action', 'method'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $profiles = Profile::all();
    $statustypes = StatusType::all();
    $udns = Udn::all();
    $usertypes = UserType::all();
    $action = route('user.update', $user->id);
    $method = 'PUT';

    return view('user.create', compact('user', 'profiles', 'statustypes', 'udns', 'usertypes', 'action', 'method'));
}
```

```
<form method="post" action="{{ $action }}" id="form-search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}     
    <div>
       <label for="">Nombre:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{ $user->first_name }}">
       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="{{ $method }}">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Apellidos:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{ $user->last_name }}">
    </div>        
    <div>
        <label>Correo:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}">
    </div>        
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ $user->password }}">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Perfil:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name='profile_id'>
            <option value="" disabled{{ ! $user->profile_id ? ' selected' : '' }}>---Selecciona una opción---</option>
            @foreach($profiles as $profile)
                <option value="{{ $profile->id }}"{{ ($user->profile_id == $profile->id) ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{ $profile->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Tipo de estado:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name='status_type_id'>
            <option value="" disabled{{ ! $user->status_type_id ? ' selected' : '' }}>---Selecciona una opción---</option>
            @foreach($statustypes as $statustype)
                <option value="{{ $statustype->id }}"{{ ($user->status_type_id == $statustype->id) ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{ $statustype->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <label>Udn:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name='udn_id'>
            <option value="" disabled{{ ! $user->udn_id ? ' selected' : '' }}>---Selecciona una opción---</option>
            @foreach($udns as $udn)
                <option value="{{ $udn->id }}"{{ ($user->udn_id == $udn->id) ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{ $udn->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div> 
    <div>
        <label>Tipo de usuario:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name='user_type_id'>
            <option value="" disabled{{ ! $user->user_type_id ? ' selected' : '' }}>---Selecciona una opción---</option>
            @foreach($usertypes as $usertype)
                <option value="{{ $usertype->id }}"{{ ($user->user_type_id == $usertype->id) ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{ $usertype->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ $user->id ? 'Actualizar' : 'Guardar' }}</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Puede ser que haya pasado algo por alto, pero espero se entienda la lógica.

Comment: Gracias amigo ya me quedo, me puedes explicar lo que hiciste? y dime colo le hago para componer ese button "cancelar" te lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: @LuisGerardo lo que hice fue utilizar tu vista de creación pero la agregué algunos condicionales para que se adapte a la vista de edición. Si revisás los `<select>` vas a ver que chequeo si el valor que tiene asignado el usuario es igual al del option actual. Si es así, le agrego `selected`. El resto está en los comentarios del controlador. Variables para el `action` y el `method` del formulario. Con LaravelCollective se puede simplificar bastante el formulario.